# React router dom dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am doing a React.js project. I am retrieving dat from the [Star Wars API](https://www.swapi.tech/) rendering a list of films on the screen and now I am trying to route every film to its own page through react-router-dom. Unfortunately, I am not able to make it work. it crash when I try to routing dynamically.

UPDATE AFTER ANSWER OF REZA

This is the App.js:

```
import './App.css';    
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";    
import Home from './components/Home';
import ItemContainer from './components/ItemContainer';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {
  return (
      <>
      <Navbar />
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route exact path="/:movieId" element={<ItemContainer />} />
        </Routes> 
        </> 
  );
}    
export default App;
```

This is the ItemContainer:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";    
import MovieDetail from "../MovieDetail";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";    
const ShowMovie = (movieId) => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState([]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetch("https://www.swapi.tech/api/films/");
        const json = await res.json();
        setResult(json.result);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return new Promise((res) => 
    res(result.find((value) => value.properties.title === movieId)))
}

const ItemContainer = () => {
    const [films, setFilms] = useState([]);
    const { movieId } = useParams([]);
    console.log('params movieId container', movieId)

    useEffect(() => {
        ShowMovie(movieId).then((value) => {
            setFilms(value.properties.title)
        })
    }, [movieId])
    return (
            <MovieDetail key={films.properties.title} films={films} />
    );
}     
export default ItemContainer;
```

The console.log doesn't give anything.

### UPDATE

Also, this is the whole code in [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-cookies-j94or?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: `films` is initially an array, but you are accessing it like it is an object, i.e. `films.properties.title`. Which is it? You are accessing like an object when setting component `key` but passing the entire `films` state as a prop.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese I fixed that. But even though that, it renders a blank page. It does that even if I change the return of ItemContainer to a <h1> or a <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowMovie` is declared like a React component, but used like a utility function. You shouldn't directly invoke React function components. React functions are also to be synchronous, pure functions. `ShowMovie` is returning a `Promise` with makes it an asynchronous function.

Convert `ShowMovie` into a utility function, which will basically call `fetch` and process the JSON response.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";    
import MovieDetail from "../MovieDetail";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const showMovie = async (movieId) => {
  const res = await fetch("https://www.swapi.tech/api/films/");
  const json = await res.json();
  const movie = json.result.find((value) => value.properties.episode_id === Number(movieId)));

  if (!movie) {
    throw new Error("No match found.");
  }

  return movie;
}

const ItemContainer = () => {
  const [films, setFilms] = useState({});
  const { movieId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('params movieId container', movieId);

    showMovie(movieId)
      .then((movie) => {
        setFilms(movie);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // handle error/log it/show message/ignore/etc...

        setFilms({}); // maintain state invariant of object
      });
  }, [movieId]);

  return (
    <MovieDetail key={films.properties?.title} films={films} />
  );
};

export default ItemContainer;
```

### Update

1. The `route` path should include `movieId`, the param you are accessing in `ItemContainer`. The sub-path `"film"` should match what you link from in `Home`. In `Home` ensure you link to the `/"film/...."` path.

   ```
   <Routes>
     <Route path="/films" element={<Home />} />
     <Route path="/film/:movieId" element={<ItemContainer />} />
     <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/films" />} />
   </Routes>
   ```
2. In `ItemContainer` you should be matching a movie object's `episode_id` property to the `movieId` value. Store the ***entire*** movie object into state, not just the title.

   ```
   const showMovie = async (movieId) => {
     const res = await fetch("https://www.swapi.tech/api/films/");
     const json = await res.json();
     const movie = json.result.find((value) => value.properties.episode_id === Number(movieId)));

     if (!movie) {
       throw new Error("No match found.");
     }

     return movie;
   }
   ```

   ...

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("params movieId container", movieId);

     showMovie(movieId)
       .then((movie) => {
         setFilms(movie);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         // handle error/log it/show message/ignore/etc...

         setFilms({}); // maintain state invariant of object
       });
   }, [movieId]);
   ```
3. You should also use Optional Chaining on the more deeply nested `films` prop object properties in `MovieDetail`, or conditionally render `MovieDetail` only if the `films` state has something to display.

   ```
   const MovieDetail = ({ films }) => {
     return (
       <div>
         <h1>{films.properties?.title}</h1>
         <h3>{films.description}</h3>
       </div>
     );
   };
   ```

Demo:

[image: Edit confident-mendel-hscz5]

Comment: Thanks so much Drew for the explanation and the code. However, the routing isn't working. It goes to a blank page. But, if in App.js I change the route from /films to /film, it goes to a blank pge as well but there I cn see the navbar, nothing else. Either way I use there is a warning with the mesage: index.tsx:25 No routes matched location "/films/1". Also, the console.log from that component doesn't show up on the dev tools. There is an updated sandbox in the post with your new code added.

Comment: @JoaquinPalacios You had a few things mixed up. Searching for film by title compared against the episode id, the path, etc... Please check update to answer with forked CSB.

Comment: Thanks for your help Drew. I learnt a lot thanks to your post.

Answer (score 2):

Modify App.js like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route exact path="/MovieDetail/:movieId" element={<ItemContainer />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reza. It works, but it doesn't route to ItemContainer.